# How do I limit task tags to current project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse currently shows the task tags (`// TODO`) from all open projects.  I would be grateful if anyone could point out the preference, where I could restrict the scope of tasks displayed (e.g. only tasks from current project).

Answer (score 155):

In Eclipse Helios (3.6) you can configure the scope.

Down arrow at the top right -> Configure Contents:

[image: Configure Contents img]

Select a configuration on the left (or create a new one) and on the right in the Scope section select "On any element in same project".

Comment: I had to deselect "Show all items" at the very top, too.

Answer (score 10):

There should be a down arrow in the top-right with several options in it. For the old Eclipse the option you want is Filters... And for the newer Eclipse the option is now Configure Contents. At the top of the Configure Contents dialog is a scope selection with options you want, I think.. If not check preferences and search for tasks, or scope. It should be in there somewhere.

Comment: This allows you to keep other projects open, but only see todos from the current project. I recommend this option. However, Tilman's answer covers the same content and is more precise!

Comment: @MichaelHerold Can't agree with you, to me this one was very helpful, because it helped me find that triangle.

Answer (score 9):

Close projects that you aren't working on.  Tasks show for any part of the workspace, so remove projects that you arent working on by doing a close operation.  (right click on the project in the project explorer and then "close project")

Comment: what about libraries your are using -> medium plan :=) but thx anyways

Answer (score 5):

**Configure Contents...** can be used to filter to things like working sets (if you're not already using working sets, you should), but yet another way is to use **Mylyn** to filter out any UI elements not relevant for what you're currently working on.

Answer (score 5):

**In Eclipse 2019-06:**

**1-** Open the **Tasks** window. 
**2-** Click on the arrow pointing down `▽`. 
**3-** Click on `Filters...` 
[image]

**4-** In the `Configurations` panel on the left select **TODOs** (or any configuration that you have saved).
**5-** Under `Scope` select `On elements in selected projects`
[image]

**6-** Click on **Apply and Close**
 
 
Now the task view will only show the tasks of the project where you are at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Simply close the projects you are not working on.
You can leave them in the workspace, too.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Juno 4.2.1, I found that it's possible to disable specific projects `TODO` tasks.

In the projects properties open:
**Java Compiler > Task Tags**

From that page check the option "Enable project specific settings" and remove the `TODO` entry from the list below, after that the `TODO` comments from that project won't be shown in Tasks.
You could also remove other tags from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by working sets works fine, but I had to put the packages into a working set, rather than the whole project.

Answer (score -3):

AFAIK the Eclipse task list is workspace-based and cannot really be filtered by default.

Comment: The task list can be filtered on all sorts of things, such as working sets.

Comment: Yes, by working sets, but AFAIK you can't filter it at a project-level.